# Retrieve Results from JSON Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm still very new to JS and jQuery but am wondering how to search and retrieve some results from a JSON file.

My html looks like this:

```
<form name="fetch">
    <input type="text" id="query">
    <input type="submit" id="search" value="Go">
</form>

<section id="main"></section>
```

and my JS like this:

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

    var search = $('#query').val();

    var output="<h2>Search results for " + search + "</h2>";

    for (var i in data.places) {
        for (var ind in data.places[i].service[0].type) {
            if (data.places[i].service[0].type[ind].name == search) {
                output+="<h3>" + data.places[i].name + "</h3>";
            } else {}
        };
    };
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=output;
});

$('#fetch form').on('submit', data);

});
```

I'm storing the value of the input field in a variable called `search` but when I git "Go" it doesn't seem to give me any results. However, If I hardcode the `input` field in the HTML with a `value=""` attribute from my JSON object, it returns the data.

I just can't work out how to save what's inputted in the search variable and return the results with that function.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Attached some JSON data below:

```
 {
  "places":[
    {
      "name": "The Whittington Hospital",
      "service": [{
        "type": [
          { "name": "Hernia Repair" },
          { "name": "Hip Replacement" },
          { "name": "Crohn's Disease" },
          { "name": "Pregnancy" }
        ]
      }]
      },
      {
      "name": "University College Hospital",
      "service": [{
        "type": [
          { "name": "Hernia Repair" },
          { "name": "Pregnancy" }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your search function runs only once (while your page is being loaded)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife

Comment: And if your data.json doesn't really change along the way you could load it just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `$('#fetch form').on('submit', data);` is most likely wrong (*no method called `data` in your code*)

You likely need this

```
$(function() {

    function performSearch(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

            var search = $('#query').val();

            var output="<h2>Search results for " + search + "</h2>";

            for (var i in data.places) {
                for (var ind in data.places[i].service[0].type) {
                    if (data.places[i].service[0].type[ind].name == search) {
                        output+="<h3>" + data.places[i].name + "</h3>";
                    } else {}
                };
            };
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=output;
        });
    };

    $('#fetch').on('submit', performSearch);

});
```

---

Or (*since your JSON is static and you do the search client-side*)

```
$(function() {
    var data;

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(jsondata) { data = jsondata; });

    function performSearch(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (data == undefined) return; // do nothing if json is not yet loaded

        var search = $('#query').val();
        var output="<h2>Search results for " + search + "</h2>";

        for (var i in data.places) {
            for (var ind in data.places[i].service[0].type) {
                if (data.places[i].service[0].type[ind].name == search) {
                    output+="<h3>" + data.places[i].name + "</h3>";
                } else {}
            };
        };
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=output;
    };

    $('#fetch').on('submit', performSearch);

});
```

---

**update**

A couple of errors:

1. `$('#fetch form')` target a form under an element with `id="fetch"`.

   - but you use `name` instead of `id` so the handler is not bound
   - the `name` (that should be `id`) attribute exists on the form itself, and not on a parent of it.

So you need to change the html to `<form id="fetch">` and the jquery to bind directly to it with `$('#fetch').on('submit', performSearch);`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/44wM5/2/

Comment: I can't get either of those to work. I've setup a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/realph/44wM5/

Comment: @realph you need to provide us with some sample json data

Comment: @realph added update and working demo at end of answer.. (*in the demo i have used `$.post` to get the json, but that is just a requirement of jsfiddle. do not change how you acquire the json*)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to try reading up on this a bit more to understand it all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        window.data = data;
        // Data loaded
    });
}

function search(query) {
    var output="<h2>Search results for " + query + "</h2>";
    for (var i in data.places) { // consider jQuery.each
        for (var ind in data.places[i].service[0].type) {
            if (data.places[i].service[0].type[ind].name == query) {
                output+="<h3>" + data.places[i].name + "</h3>";
            } else {}
        };
    };
    $('#main').html(output);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Choose which data to load propably?
    loadData(); // Load data when you're ready
    // and anything else
});
$('#fetch form').on('submit', function() {
    var query = $('#query').val();
    search(query); // Call search function whenever you want, using any query
});
```